# How to escape a PCRE pattern with bash (ag)

Tags: bash, shell, ag

### Question

How do I escape a regex (PCRE) to use in bash (with [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher))?

### Attempts

```sh
ag (?!.*rib)(?=.*dist)^(\w+)$ # -bash: !.*wib: event not found
ag "(?!.*rib)(?=.*dist)^(\w+)$" # -bash: !.*wib: event not found
ag '(?!.*rib)(?=.*dist)^(\w+)$' # This does not crash, but finds nothing
ag (\?!.\*rib)(\?=.\*dist)^(\\w+)$ # -bash: !.*wib: event not found
```

**Edit**: I was incorrect - the third one above finds nothing (but it does seem to be thinking hard)

I'm using osx

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: The third option should work fine `ag '(?!.*rib)(?=.*dist)^(\w+)$'`. The `!` is the history expansion character which needs to be quoted

Comment: Ah, Sorry. The third option does not crash, but it does not find anything at all

Answer (score 2):

Aaah, these are the damn exclamation marks :-) This message "event not found" because of the unescaped `!` exclamation mark. Try with some random string:

```
echo !asdjweuwioeuoiu 
# -bash: !asdjweuwioeuoiu: event not found
```

But if you escape with quotation marks, it should not be expanded and interpreted by bash:

```
echo '!fkj90eruge90ru0e9ger0g'
# !fkj90eruge90ru0e9ger0g
```

So, the third line of your suggestions should work:

```
ag '(?!.*rib)(?=.*dist)^(\w+)$'
```

Comment: Ah, Sorry. The third option does not crash, but it does not find anything at all

Comment: @AshleyCoolman that's a different issue then :) Perhaps you need to debug your regex, who knows.

Comment: Ugh. It was a badly written question. The regex works, but...yeah i need to include an example. I feel like maybe im assuming a feature of the regex engine. Anyway ill fix the q when i get infront of a physical keyboard

Comment: @AshleyCoolman please write a different question for it. This one was about the "event not found" problem and this one is actually solved. Create a new question for the other problem.

Comment: quick historical reminder of the !: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash -- consider disabling the "feature."

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a file, foo.txt with four lines of the following text:

```
distribute
distrib
distrubte
dist
```

Then using ag from bash, you'd employ your regex as follows:

```
$ ag "(?\!.*rib)(?=.*dist)" foo.txt
3:distrubte
4:dist
```

Line 3 and 4 would return as found matches. Note: I used double quotes, not single and ONLY escaped the exclamation mark -- as I didn't want it interpreted by bash, but used in the regex. If I wanted it used, I could do something like this:

```
$echo dist
dist
$ag "!$$" foo.txt 
4:dist
```

Now line four is matched. What happened here is the `!$` of `!$$` was expanded by the shell as the last argument to the previous command, i.e. `dist`. And, the final `$` was left as a literal, making the expanded command `ag "dist$"`, and this matches the fourth line in file.

For this reason, I actually prefer to use/struggle with double quotes since they afford one the ability to swap in variables, arguments, and shell capabilities into Ag's search string. YMMV.